# R - How to get max() to return variable names instead of contents of the variables?

Tags: r, max, variable-names

I need to find the max value from a list of variables.  However, max() returns the contents of the variable instead of the variable name.  Is there a way to get the name instead of the content?

Quick example code:

```
jan <- 0
feb <- 0
mar <- 0

#for testing purposes - just select a random month and add 10
s1 <- sample(1:3, 1)
if (s1==1) {
  jan <- jan + 10
}
if (s1==2) {
  feb <- feb + 10
}
if (s1==3) {
  mar <- mar + 10
}

final <- max(jan, feb, mar)

final
```

The result from that will always be 10.  That isn't helpful...  Is there a way to get the month/variable name returned instead? (ie "jan" instead of "10")

Thank you!

Comment: I also tried adding labels to the list, but the labels are not carried over with max()

Comment: You can name your vector elements to begin with, e.g.: `jan <- c(jan=0); feb <- c(feb=0); mar <- c(mar=0)`, and then `final <- which.max(jan, feb, mar)` will also be named. Access with `names(final)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try:

```
 c("jan", "feb", "mar")[which.max(c(jan, feb, mar))]
 #[1] "jan"
```

Comment: Thank you - this works perfectly.  I had tried subsetting but apparently had something wrong...

Comment: @jdfinch3 Glad to know it works. Could you show the code for subsetting in your post.

Comment: Sorry, it's long since deleted as it didn't work.  I believe I had the order backwards.  Thanks. :)